# Is implicitly using null argument as a flag good code style

Tags: c#, coding-style

Which of below is a better coding style, and why?
1)

```
public string GetValue(string setting, string error)
{
    var val = GetSettingFromSomewhere(setting);
    if (val==null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) throw Exception(error);
    return val;
}
```

Or
2)

```
public string GetValue(string setting, bool isRequired, string error)
{
    var val = GetSettingFromSomewhere(setting);
    if (val==null && isRequired) throw Exception(error);
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Don't create entities beyond necessity. Does it semantically make sense to pass *null*? If there is no contradictions, there is no reason to pass yet another variable. Also this question as written provokes opinionated answers which is a no-no.

Comment: One possibility: rename `error` to `errorIfMissing` to clarify that the parameter serves the dual purpose of indicating whether the parameter is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Clean Code book flags are not recommended. You can beter make two different methods, one named GetRequiredValue and one named GetOptionalValue. The error string seems reduntant to me, use a custom made exception ("GetSettingFromSomewhereException") and pass the setting value.

Answer (score 0):

IsNullOrEmpty function is Light and it's returning a Boolean so I guess for this case in particular it doesn't really matter. What matters is what you think makes your function more readable to the people who might use the function